# SML - Get Indices of List

Tags: list, sml

I'm working on a program that appends either a '+' or '-' to an element of a list, depending on whether the index of that element is odd or even (i.e an  alternating sums list).

However, I'm having trouble identifying what the index of each element is. I have code that I believe should append the correct symbol, using `if statements`  and `mod`

```
fun alternating([]) = 0
  | alternating(l) = 
        if List.nth(l,hd(l)) mod 2 == 0 then '+'@hd(l)@alternating(tl(l))
        else '-'@hd(l)@alternating(tl(l))
```

However, `List.nth(l,hd(l))` always returns the element at the second index, not the first.

Comment: An example of the input and expected output would be helpful. Is the input a list of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the off chance that you really just want to negate integers them so you can pass them into some kind of summation, I would just negate the argument if it's odd. Using mutual recursion one can do it without any explicit index bookkeeping:

```
fun alternate l =
   let
       fun alternate1 []      = []
         | alternate1 (x::xs) = (~x) :: alternate2 xs
       and alternate2 []      = []
         | alternate2 (x::xs) =   x  :: alternate1 xs
   in
       alternate1 l
   end
```

It works like so:

```
- alternate [1,2,3,4];
val it = [~1,2,~3,4] : int list
```

I would strongly encourage you to use pattern matching instead of `hd`.

**Edit** discussing `hd`

As a rule of thumb, if you need `hd` you probably need `tl` as well. `hd` is a partial function--it's going to throw `Empty` if your list is empty. If you pattern match, you conveniently get variables for the head and tail of the list right there, and you get a visual reminder that you need to handle the empty list. It's more aesthetically pleasing, IMO, to see:

```
fun foo []      = ...
  | foo (x::xs) = ...
```

than the equivalent

```
fun foo l = 
  if null l 
    then ... 
    else (hd l) ... (tl l)
```

In other words, you get shorter, cleaner code with an automatic reminder to make it correct. Win/win. To my knowledge there's no significant advantage to doing it the other way. Of course, you may find yourself in a situation where you know the list will have at least one element and you don't need to do anything else. You still have to consider the cases you're given, but it's a good rule of thumb.

Comment: @Delfini I've expanded on that in the answer.

Comment: I'll agree that `x::xs` is much nicer to look at :)

Comment: I tried the above code and received an error message. `Operator is not a function: operator: ^Z list in expression: let local var <pat> = <exp> in val <pat> = <exp> val <pat> = <exp> end in alternate l end alternate`

Comment: @Delfini I think you have a copy/paste error. I just pasted it from the answer on another machine and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to decorate your list with an index you could try something like the following

```
fun add_index l =
  let 
    fun add_index_helper (nil,  _) = nil
      | add_index_helper (h::tl,i) = (h,i) :: add_index_helper (tl,1+i)
  in
     add_index_helper (l,0)
  end

val x = add_index [0,1,4,9,16,25]
```

but you can also just directly compute parity with the same method

```
fun add_sign l =
  let 
    fun add_sign_helper (nil,  _) = nil
      | add_sign_helper (h::tl,i) = (h,i) :: add_sign_helper (tl,1-i)
  in
     add_sign_helper (l,0)
  end

val y = add_sign [0,1,4,9,16,25]
```

then you can map the parity to a string

```
fun sign_to_char (x,0) = (x,"+")
  | sign_to_char (x,_) = (x,"-")

val z = List.map sign_to_char y
```

or you can just add the sign directly

```
fun add_char l =
  let 
    fun add_char_helper (nil,  _) = nil
      | add_char_helper (h::tl,0) = (h,"+") :: add_char_helper (tl,1)
      | add_char_helper (h::tl,_) = (h,"-") :: add_char_helper (tl,0)
  in
     add_char_helper (l,0)
  end

val zz = add_char [0,1,4,9,16,25]
```

Alternatively if you had a string list and you wanted to add chars you could try something like this

```
fun signs L =
  let
    datatype parity = even | odd
    fun signs_helper ( nil ,_) = nil
      | signs_helper (x::xs,even) = ("+" ^ x) :: signs_helper(xs,odd)
      | signs_helper (x::xs,odd)  = ("-" ^ x) :: signs_helper(xs,even)
  in
    signs_helper (L,even)
  end

val z = signs ["x","2y","3z","4"]
(* this gives you val z = ["+x","-2y","+3z","-4"] : string list *)
```