# SML - Alternating Sum Using Pattern Matching

Tags: list, sml

I'm writing a program that accepts a list of `int` and returns the value of their alternating sum.

```
Input: [1,2,3,4]
Output: 1 + (-2) + 3 + (-4)
```

Below is the code I tried to write for doing this, but I keep getting the error `syntax error: inserting ORELSE`

My `if then else` statement looks correct, so I'm not sure what could be causing the error

```
fun alternate([]) = 0
  | alternate(x::xs, count) = 
        count = count + 1
        if count mod 2 == 0 then (~x) + alternate(xs)
        else x + alternate(xs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is caused by that `count = count + 1` and `if ... else ...` are multiple expressions. If you want to execute multiple expressions, you can write the code like this:

```
(expression1;
 expression2;
     ...
 expressionN);
```

There are two other errors in your code.
1. The parameters are not the same type in different pattern clauses of the function `alternate`.
2. In SML `=` indicates equality, not `==`.

So a correct solution may look like this:

```
fun alternate([]) = 0
  | alternate(x::xs) =
      let 
        fun alt([], count) = 0
          | alt(x::xs, count) =
              if count mod 2 = 0 then x + alt(xs, count+1)
              else (~x) + alt(xs, count+1)
      in 
        alt(x::xs, 0)
      end;
```

Comment: What's the purpose of defining the function in the `let` clause?

Comment: @Delfini functions defined in the `let` clause have access to everything bound in the outer scope and their visibility is restricted to the `in` portion of the `let` clause. In this case it's letting you hide the helper function inside the scope of the function whose API is public. It's somewhat like making a private method in an OO language, except the scope is the containing function rather than the containing object. It's hygienic.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26663361/812818) I would suggest implementing `sum`:

```
val sum = foldr (op +) 0;
```

Copying the `alternate` function from that answer here for completeness, with a small bugfix:

```
fun alternate l =
   let
       fun alternate1 []      = []
         | alternate1 (x::xs) =   x  :: alternate2 xs
       and alternate2 []      = []
         | alternate2 (x::xs) = (~x) :: alternate1 xs
   in
       alternate1 l
   end
```

Then you can define `alternate_sum` quite simply:

```
val alternate_sum = sum o alternate
```

There will of course be objections in the name of performance. Haskell is able to perform deforestation/fusion optimizations across these sorts of invocations because it knows something about the purity of the functions; Standard ML does not *require* these optimizations though some implementations may attempt them, I don't know.

The overhead on this particular problem may or may not be absurd, but I think it's a good example of functional programming principles regardless: building up complex behavior from simpler, unimpeachable behavior. The "burden of proof" in this version is almost all on `alternate`. @SunsetRider's version is fine (it will probably perform better) but the code is more "monolithic" you might say.

Also, @SunsetRider's code is a little more complex than it needs to be, this version is sufficient:

```
fun alternate l =
  let 
    fun alt([], count) = 0
      | alt(x::xs, count) =
          if count mod 2 = 0 then x + alt(xs, count+1)
          else (~x) + alt(xs, count+1)
  in 
    alt(l, 0)
  end
```

One comment in addition to what @SunsetRider said: in general, in functional languages `x = x + 1` and other mutations are a bit of a code smell. You can see that in their code they use `count+1` several times instead. Thinking functionally, what matters is what expressions are evaluating to, not the state of variables, so the values that are passed around are critical. This goes back to the **superb** definition at the beginning of the excellent and hugely underrated book [*Functional C* by Pieter Hartel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201419505):

> The functional and imperative paradigms operate from different viewpoints. The functional paradigm is based on the *evaluation of expressions* and binding variables to values. The basic program phrase is the expression, the purpose of evaluating an expression is to produce a value. The order in which subexpressions are evaluated does not affect the resulting value.
>
> The imperative paradigm is based on the *execution of statements* and having a store where the statements can leave their results. The basic program phrase is the statement; the purpose of executing a statement is to change the store. The order in which statements are executed *does* affect the resulting values in the store. The current set of values in the store is referred to as the *state* of the program.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a mention in any answer that tracking this count is wholly unnecessary with the key term *pattern-matching* in the title. We can match on more than just the first element and tail of a list.

- For an empty list, the answer is `0`.
- For a list with a single element, the answer is that single element.
- For a list with at least two elements, we subtract the second from the first and add the result of recursively calling `alternate` on the tail.

```
fun alternate([]) = 0
  | alternate([x]) = x
  | alternate(a::b::tl) = a - b + alternate(tl);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here alternative solution

```
altSum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
altSum (x:[]) = x
altSum (x:y:xs) = x - y + altSum xs
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of why your alternative solution might be preferred? Are there tradeoffs to this approach that make it especially suitable to particular situations?

Comment: And why offer a Haskell solution to a question about SML?

Answer (score -1):

```
altsum n = x1 -x2 +x3 -x4 +... +xn
      = x1 -(x2 -x3 +x4 +...+xn)
      = x1 - altsum(n-1)

fun altsum [] = 0
  | altsum x::xs = x - altsum xs`
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply